# publish arrays to a topic on the command line

Tags: ros, topic, message, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am new to ROS and experimenting with several things. Now I have the following problem:
I want to define a topic where the type contains arrays of strings and floats. So I wrote a file Arrays.msg that contains

```
string[] name
float32[] value
```

and a simple Subscriber node:

```
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest("playground")
import rospy
from playground.msg import Arrays

def callback(data):
        print "test"

def main():
        rospy.init_node("array_test_node")
        sub = rospy.Subscriber("array_test", Arrays, callback)
        rospy.spin()

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Now my question is: How do I publish a list of strings and floats on the command line? It works when I type

```
rostopic pub /array_test playground/Arrays -- ["Foo"] [1.1]
```

and it publishes the correct message on /array_test. But what if I have more strings? I tried

```
rostopic pub /array_test playground/Arrays -- ["Foo", "Bar"] [1.1, 2.2]
```

but I get the following error message:

```
rostopic: error: Argument error: while parsing a flow node
expected the node content, but found '<stream end>'
    in "<string>", line 1, column 6:
    [Foo,
         ^
```

What would be the correct command for publishing these arrays on the command line?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10244/publish-arrays-to-a-topic-on-the-command-line/) by [TillScout](https://answers.ros.org/users/686/tillscout/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2011-06-13

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try this:

```
rostopic pub /array_test playground/Arrays "{name:['Foo', 'Bar'], value:[1.1, 2.2]}"
```

**EDIT** - the inner quotes don't seem to be required, even with spaces in the string, so this also works:

```
rostopic pub /array_test playground/Arrays "{name:[Some words, More words], value:[1.1, 2.2]}"
```

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) with karma: 2264 on 2011-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 12

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TillScout](https://answers.ros.org/users/686/tillscout/) on 2011-06-14**:
Hmm, yes it works, but it is a bit clumsy. Why are the qoutes and the curly brackets necessary?

**Comment by [TillScout](https://answers.ros.org/users/686/tillscout/) on 2011-06-13**:
That works, thank you!